# Issue in opening the 8MP H264 Stream from tcp server

Tags: c++, c, qt, ffmpeg, h.264

I am facing issue in opening the raw h264 stream of 8MP resolution over tcp server from Android in Qt Application. To open the stream in ffplay, I give following command in terminal and it is able to play it

```
ffplay -f h264 -codec:v h264 -probesize 32M <tcp://ipaddress:port>
```

But when I try to open the stream in Qt Application, **avformat_open_input()** gives error **Invalid data found while processing input**.
Below is the code I am using in Qt Application:

```
 av_register_all();
 avcodec_register_all();
 avformat_network_init();
 AVFormatContext *refrenceFormatCtx = NULL;
 SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
 AVIOContext *avio_ctx = NULL;
 int video_stream_index = 0;
 AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = NULL;
 AVSampleFormat *fmt = NULL;
 char errorsdef[100];
 AVDictionary *options = NULL;
 av_dict_set(&options, "video_size","3264x2448",0);
 av_dict_set(&options,"pixel_format","yuv420p",0);
 av_dict_set(&options, "f", "h264", 0);
 av_dict_set(&options, "codec:v", "h264", 0);
 av_dict_set(&options, "codec:a", "aac", 0);
 av_dict_set(&options, "probesize", "32M", 0);

  int err = avformat_open_input(&refrenceFormatCtx,"tcp://192.168.42.129:2226", NULL, &options);
  av_strerror(err,errorsdef,100);
  qDebug() << "OPening Stream error: "<< err << " "<< errorsdef;
  if(err<0)
      abort();
  av_dict_free(&options);
```

Is the path to set the options in avformat_open_input is correct? Are parameters set by me are correct?

Comment: In what part of your example is there some Qt code that is not just print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my above asked question. Code for the issue and getting rgb frames from raw H.264 Frame for 8MP resolution is as follows:

```
avcodec_register_all();
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();

AVDictionary *options = NULL;
AVFormatContext *refrenceFormatCtx = NULL;
AVInputFormat *fmts = av_find_input_format("h264");
char errorsdef[100];
AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = NULL;
int video_stream_index = 0;    
SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = NULL;
AVFrame* picture_yuv = NULL;
AVFrame* picture_rgb = NULL;
uint8_t* picture_buffer_rgb;
uint8_t *rgb_image_data;
int sizeofrgbpicture = 0;
int initialize_rgb_requirements=1;
picture_yuv = av_frame_alloc();

av_dict_set(&options, "flags", "bicubic", 0);
av_opt_set(refrenceFormatCtx,"f","h264", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
av_opt_set(refrenceFormatCtx,"codec:v","h264",AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
av_opt_set(refrenceFormatCtx,"probesize","32M", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);

// Open video file
int err = avformat_open_input(&refrenceFormatCtx,"tcp://192.168.42.129:2226", fmts, &options);
if (!options) {
    int dict_count = av_dict_count(options);
    qDebug() << "dict_count " << dict_count;
}
av_strerror(err,errorsdef,100);
qDebug() << "OPening Stream error: "<< err << " "<< errorsdef;
if (refrenceFormatCtx!=NULL){
    err = avformat_find_stream_info(refrenceFormatCtx, &options);
    if( err< 0){
        av_strerror(err,errorsdef,100);
        qDebug() << "Not able to find stream: "<< err << " "<< errorsdef;
    }
}else{
    qDebug() << "referencecontext null";
    exit(1);
}
//search video stream
for (int i = 0; i < (int)refrenceFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    AVStream* s = refrenceFormatCtx->streams[i];
    if (s->codec == NULL){
        continue;
    }
    codec_ctx = (s->codec);
    if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
        video_stream_index = i;
    }
}
AVPacket packet;
av_init_packet(&packet);

//open output file
AVFormatContext* output_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
AVStream* stream = NULL;

//start reading packets from stream and emit data pointer to slot
av_read_play(refrenceFormatCtx);    //play RTSP
avcodec_copy_context(codec_ctx, refrenceFormatCtx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec);

if (avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264), NULL) < 0){
    qDebug() << "avcodec_open2 null";
}
while (av_read_frame(refrenceFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
    if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index) {    //packet is video
        if (stream == NULL) {    //create stream in file
            stream = avformat_new_stream(output_ctx, refrenceFormatCtx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec->codec);
            avcodec_copy_context(stream->codec, refrenceFormatCtx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec);
            stream->sample_aspect_ratio = refrenceFormatCtx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec->sample_aspect_ratio;
        }
        int check = 0;
        packet.stream_index = stream->id;
        int result = avcodec_decode_video2(codec_ctx, picture_yuv, &check, &packet);
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
        if(result <= 0 || check == 0){
            continue;
        }
        if(initialize_rgb_requirements)
        {
            sizeofrgbpicture = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);
            picture_rgb = av_frame_alloc();
            picture_buffer_rgb = (uint8_t*) (av_malloc(sizeofrgbpicture));
            avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) picture_rgb, picture_buffer_rgb, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);
            img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            initialize_rgb_requirements=0;
        }
        int height = 0;
        if(picture_yuv->data != NULL)
        {
            height = sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, ((AVPicture*)picture_yuv)->data, ((AVPicture*)picture_yuv)->linesize, 0, codec_ctx->height, ((AVPicture*)picture_rgb)->data,((AVPicture*)picture_rgb)->linesize);
        }
        rgb_image_data = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeofrgbpicture * sizeof(uint8_t));
        int ret = avpicture_layout((AVPicture *)picture_rgb, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, rgb_image_data, sizeofrgbpicture);
        emit imageQueued(rgb_image_data, codec_ctx->width,codec_ctx->height);
    }
    msleep(1);
}
av_freep(picture_buffer_rgb);
av_frame_free(&picture_rgb);
avio_close(output_ctx->pb);
avformat_free_context(output_ctx);
avformat_close_input(&refrenceFormatCtx);
```

I came to know that for raw H.264 stream we have to tell ffmpeg that the format is h264.  For that I have used `AVInputFormat`, to set other options like video codec and probesize, I have used `av_op_set()`. To set the default flags in ffmpeg, I have used `av_dict_set()`. I have emitted the data pointer to my required slot. If any one wants to create a file from it, then it can generate .ppm file by writing this pointer into file.